# Rails ActiveRecord STI: Limit scope to Parent Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
Class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :exclusive, -> { where(type: [nil, '']) }
end

Class Ophthalmologist < Physician; end
```

How can I make the scope "exclusive" available only to Physician?

Comment: `type` will never be blank

Answer (score 2):

I should start with: type will never be blank for STI. If it is it will fail to create the model.

To answer your question though, you can limit scope of any method to parent class with:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :exclusive, -> { where(type: [nil, '']) }

  def self.inherited(mod)
    super               # allow rails to do its thing
    class << mod
      undef :exclusive
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I can create a Physician without a type. Did you rather mean that it is not a good practice? Also, i'm getting an error:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_module, expecting ')' def self.inherited(module)

Comment: @mdm414ZX - You can't. Rails will automatically set this column to 'Physician' on save.

Comment: That's odd. I can save it with nil type. I'm using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1 BTW.

Comment: @mdm414ZX - Have you changed self.inheritance_column? Also, are you sure it is saved?

Comment: @mdm414ZX - Fixed syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks. It quite got messed up, though: "Reader.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" AND "Physician.all" returns "(Object doesn't support #inspect)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54182/discussion-between-broisatse-and-mdm414-zx).

Comment: I got it working by calling super before class << mod; not sure if it's the appropriate way, though.